# Почему выводит undefined?

Tags: javascript, html

Вот есть такой цикл, я не понимаю почему выводит `undefined1` в консоль. От чего возникает **undefined**?

```js
function t10() {
    let a10 = '';
    let result;

    for (let a = 0; a < 5; a++) {
        for (let b = 1; b <= 10; b++) {
            result += `${10 * a + b} `; 
            a10 = result; //1
            console.log(a10); //undefined1
          
            if (result < 10) {
                a10 = '0' + a10;
            }
        }
        a10 += '<br>';
    }
}

t10();
```

```html
<button class="button-primary b-10">Task-10</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

изначально в `result` лежит `undefined`, потому что вы туда ничего не положили

замените

```
let result;
```

на

```
let result = '';
```

Comment: _изначально в result лежит undefined, потому что вы туда ничего не положили_ изначально, да, но потом же в самом цикле я присваиваю переменной result это значение - result += ${10 * a + b}

Comment: @Eva вы не присваиваете(=), вы добавляете (+=) к undefined.

Comment: @Eva `result += …` --> `result = result + …` --> `result = undefined + …`

Comment: @Danis, стоит перенести пояснения в ответ